# How to hide just the excedent of the div?

Tags: html, css

Im my site, i have a div (the circle) that use position to be in that position in image, but the circle is ocupping an excedent space in the right who is forcing the view width to grow, how to hide just the excedent part of the circle?

I don't want to move the circle for another position, just hide the excedent.

[image: gif of the bug]

```css
.floating-circles .big-circle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  right: calc((-35vw / 2) + 9%);
  bottom: calc((-35vw / 2) + 14%);
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 35vw;
  height: 35vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgb(146, 28, 205);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(146, 28, 205, 1) 0%, rgba(153, 26, 177, 1) 40%, rgba(48, 35, 174, 1) 80%, rgba(48, 35, 174, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="floating-circles">
  <div class="small-circle"></div>
  <div class="big-circle"></div>
  <!-- The big-circle is the circle causing the bug -->
</div>
```

Full project code [here in github](https://github.com/Gustavo-daCosta/Tecnico-DEV-Projetos/tree/main/Desafio%20Front-End)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either prevents `body` from overflowing:

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

...or use a [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) that "cuts" everything outside of the main box:

```css
.floating-circles {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0);
  /* or clip-path: inset(0) */
  /* Thanks @TemaniAfif for the suggestion! */
}
```

Try it:

```css
.floating-circles {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0);
}


/* Demo only */

.floating-circles {
  position: relative;
  top: 4em;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.floating-circles .big-circle {
  position: absolute;
  right: -25px;
  bottom: -40px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(146, 28, 205, 1) 0%, rgba(153, 26, 177, 1) 40%, rgba(48, 35, 174, 1) 80%, rgba(48, 35, 174, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="floating-circles">
  <div class="big-circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use  `clip-path: inset(0)`